# Find subsolution items

Tags: c#, t4

I am trying to find subsolution and add items into that solution programmatically. But code that i use is not searching for subfolders.

I use code on github: [See code here please](https://github.com/renegadexx/T4.Helper/blob/master/Source/TemplateFilemanager.CS.ttinclude)

Method that i search for solution is:

```
public static IEnumerable<EnvDTE.Project> GetAllProjects(EnvDTE.DTE dte)
{
    List<EnvDTE.Project> projectList = new List<EnvDTE.Project>();

    var folders = dte.Solution.Projects.Cast<EnvDTE.Project>().Where(p=>p.Kind == EnvDTE80.ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder);

    foreach (EnvDTE.Project folder in folders)
    {
        if (folder.ProjectItems == null) continue;

        foreach (EnvDTE.ProjectItem item in folder.ProjectItems)
        {
            if (item.Object is EnvDTE.Project)
                projectList.Add(item.Object as EnvDTE.Project);
        }
    }

    var projects = dte.Solution.Projects.Cast<EnvDTE.Project>().Where(p=>p.Kind != EnvDTE80.ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder);

    if (projects.Count() > 0)
        projectList.AddRange(projects);

    return projectList;
}
```

But this is searching only main solution and sub solution. But solution that i want to find has a longer path like "MainFolder\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\SubSolution"

Comment: you have to run this in recursion with some code change !!

Comment: you right, there is also recursive method for it but i don't know how pass required paramaters. You can find method if search "FindFolderByName" in the link that shared

Comment: When i work on it today, it worked when moving 1 folder above in solution without changing path on folder. Do you any idea about it?